# Apache Wicket HTML output page - self expiring text or hiding text

Tags: javascript, html, wicket, wicket-1.5

I am developing an application and I want to display informational messages to the frontend webpage like **"new record has been added or deleted or updated"** etc.  I want the message to disappear after few seconds ( may be 10-15 seconds).

How to approach it ? The application is being developed in Apache Wicket1.5.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Edit]: this is for Wicket 1.6.. Wicket 1.5 is a bit trickier. I will look into it later.

I would recommend making a Wicket component for this; and adding Jquery javascript when the component needs to be rendered.

You can use http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/head/OnDomReadyHeaderItem.html

```
  @Override
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        response.render(OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript(yourMethod(..., component.getMarkupId())));
    }
```

I think Wicket 1.5 offers similar approachs

Comment: Using jQuery the script would be simple: `$("#yourMarkupIdHere").delay(10000).fadeOut();`

Answer (score 2):

For a pure wicket approach, you could attach an [AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/1.5.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior.html). In the `onTimer` method you could set the message to invisible and `stop()` the timer.

Another way would be to implement this in JavaScript.

Comment: I would recommend the JS approach. There's no point to make an AJAX request just to hide an element after n seconds.

Comment: @ChristophLeiter True, but on the other hand, using the pure Wicket aproach, all the code is written in one language and can be found in one place. From the point of code readability and mainainability I'd prefer to pay the price for a server roundtrip creating an empty container.

Answer (score 0):

Before I saw the responses, I did a simple trick.

The primary requirement is to show an informational message for a short time. So I used

```
            pr.getPage().info("Records details are updated successfully!");
            setResponsePage(pr.getPage());
```

pr is the PageReference object passed from the previous page.

The messages were displayed on the FeedbackPanel in the next page and I used a timer to reload the page after 10 seconds. So the message disappears.